# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '([UNNotificationRequest]) -> Void

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to get pending notification request on local notification.
It throws me error:
**"Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '([UNNotificationRequest]) -> Void' "**

My code is:

```
var notificationTitle = "\(String(describing: notificationData!["title"]))"
var notificationInterval: Int = notificationData!["interval"] as! Int
let center  =  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {(requests) -> Void in
    var notificationExist:Bool = false
    for notificationRequest in requests {
        try{
            var notificationContent:UNNotificationContent = notificationRequest.content
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of your code is throwing but this line of your code is not true:

```
try{
    var notificationContent:UNNotificationContent = notificationRequest.content
    }
```

The correct way of it is this:

```
do {
    var notificationContent:UNNotificationContent = try notificationRequest.content
}
catch {
print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do it this way ,

```
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {requests -> () in
        var notificationExist:Bool = false
        for notificationRequest in requests {
            do {
                var notificationContent:UNNotificationContent = try notificationRequest.content
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your try block. So, you can replace it as shown below.

```
guard let notificationContent:UNNotificationContent = try? notificationRequest.content else {
    print("There was an error!")
}
```